# How to switch between speakers automatically based on your location to them?

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, speakers

I'm developing a project that will use a microcontroller to play music from three different speakers. The idea is to automatically switch which speaker is playing music based on which one I'm closest to.

I do not want to use motion sensors to trigger the switching. Can I link them using Bluetooth? I'm not sure how I would use it to switch the speakers. Are there other methods of implementation I can use?

Comment: What are the overall dimensions of the project (how far apart are the speakers)? What are location detection methods you are open to using, if not motion (ultrasonic, pressure plate, IR beam, etc.)?

Comment: You may want to something wearable with RFID or wifi ,bluetooth. It seems possible to track location with these.

Comment: How do mobile phones do it with the transmission masts? Be a fun challenge to repeat that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use BLE beaconing:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy_beacon

If it's the solution you are after, and not tinkering with microcontrollers, a better overalls solution would be to use high level home automation system that can use different methods to detect presense and swith and control audio inputs and outputs.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Which part do you mean? The wikipedia link? The questions were: Can I link them using Bluetooth? My answer starts with "You can..." and I mentioned the protocols as extra. The other question was if there are other methods which I gave a generic description of.